# ¿VBA - Cómo crear una nueva WorkBook desde un CopyFromRecordset de una Tabla SQLServer?

Tags: vba

¿Alguien podrá decirme como crear un nuevo WorkBook debtro de una carpeta?

**1 - Crear Carpeta**

```
 Sub Crear_Carpeta()
  str_Dir = "c:\fac_relatorios\"

  If Dir(str_Dir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
     MkDir (str_Dir)
  End If

End Sub
```

**2 - Listado**

```
Sub rel()

    str_newWorkBook = "datos_prueba.xlsx"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    str_LineaInicio = 2

    str_SQL = " SELECT * FROM TABLA_TEST "

    rs.Open str_SQL, Cnn, 1, 1

  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
      'Me falta los codigos para grabar los datos que viene de la tabla_test

      ' ?.Cells(CInt(str_LineaInicio), 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

  End If

End Sub
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un fragmento de código de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) del método:

```
For iCols = 0 to rs.Fields.Count - 1 
   ws.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name 
Next 
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True 
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Primero realiza un bucle `for` para conocer el nombre de las columnas y ponerlas en la primera fila del Excel. Luego realiza el `CopyFromRecordset` en la primera columna de la segunda fila (A2).

Comment: Roger,
Gracias por su aporte.